# firebase/firestore/lite doesn't work with firebase emulator?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm using Firebase SDK JS 9.15.0 with Node.js 18.12.1. I'm using firebase emulator to test some Firestore operations.
If I use functions/modules from `firebase/firestore` everything works fine. While if I use the same functions/modules `firebase/firestore/lite` I got en error. Only when `connectFirestoreEmulator` is called: both modules work fine connecting directy with real Firestore.

Here is the code to test.
The working one:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, setDoc, getDoc, connectFirestoreEmulator} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
// ... Configuration here
  };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const firestoreDB = getFirestore(app);
connectFirestoreEmulator(firestoreDB, 'localhost', 8080);

const collectionRef = collection(firestoreDB, 'CollectionName');
const docRef = doc(collectionRef, "DocID");
setDoc(docRef, {
    name: "DocumentName"
  }).then(() => 
  {
        console.log("OK");
  });
```

On the other side, this return an error:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, setDoc, getDoc, connectFirestoreEmulator} from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const firebaseConfig = {
// ... Configuration here
  };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const firestoreDB = getFirestore(app);
connectFirestoreEmulator(firestoreDB, 'localhost', 8080);

const collectionRef = collection(firestoreDB, 'CollectionName');
const docRef = doc(collectionRef, "DocID");
setDoc(docRef, {
    name: "FieldName"
  }).then(() => 
  {
        console.log("OK");
  });
```

and the error is

```
[2023-01-13T11:42:51.832Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.15.0_lite): RPC_ERROR HTTP error has no status
[2023-01-13T11:42:51.835Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.15.0_lite): RestConnection Commit failed with error:  [FirebaseError: Request failed with error: undefined] {
  code: 'unknown',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
} url:  http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<my-project-name>/databases/(default)/documents:commit request: {
  writes: [
    {
      update: {
        name: 'projects/<my-project-name>/databases/(default)/documents/CollectionName/DocID',
        fields: { name: { stringValue: 'FieldName' } }
      }
    }
  ]
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[FirebaseError: Request failed with error: undefined] {
  code: 'unknown',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Does anyone have an idea if I can use firebase emulator with firestore lite?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have firebase-firestore-lite installed?

> npm install firebase-firestore-lite

Comment: Hi! no I don't but it shouldn't be needed. That module you are referring to is not official from goolge and, from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/firestore-lite, firestore lite is already present in the JS modular SDK.